# ASP.NET Core redirect after PhysicalFileResult from external link

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET core 3.1 to send an email with a link to the hosted static file. The link URL looks like `https://localhost:5001/ShareFile/DownloadFile/28` my `DownloadFile` action method is given below.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public async Task<PhysicalFileResult> DownloadFile(long id)
{
    var file = await _context.UploadedFiles.FindAsync(id);
    var wwwrootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    var uploadFolder = file.ServerPath;
    var uploadPath = Path.Combine(wwwrootPath, uploadFolder.Substring(1));
    var filePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uploadPath).Replace('/', '\\');
    return PhysicalFile(filePath, "application/octet-stream", file.Name);
}
```

As you can see, it is protected by `AuthorizeAttribute` so users must log in to access the link in the email. This works as expected and the file is downloaded after login, but **how can I redirect the user to a different URL** e.g.: `https://localhost:5001/ShareFile/Index` after the download has started?

Comment: Maybe you change the link as a button,when button click,use ajax in it to `https://localhost:5001/ShareFile/DownloadFile/xx`,and then use  `window.location.href="/ShareFile/Index"` in ajax success function

Comment: The link is in the email as mentioned in the question. So ajax is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: One Action can only return one response.What about redirecting first,and then downloading file?Without js,it's hard to do redirect after you return response.